# Terraform: loop through a list of complex objects

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I want to loop through a list of two alarms objects to be configured as below -- the problem is how to dynamically generate metric_query block by looping on every alarm metrics list..

```
   locals{
    prefix = terraform.workspace

    alarm_WithExpression = [
        { "name" : "XXX",
          "expression" : "m1/m2",
          "metrics" : [
            { "id" : "m1", "name" : "YYYY", "statistic" : "Sum", "period" : 21600 },
            { "id" : "m2", "name" : "ZZZZZ" ,"statistic" : "Sum", "period" : 21600 }
          ],
          "threshold" : 0.2,
          "comparison_operator" : "LessThanThreshold",
          "period" : 21600,
          "data_points" : 2,
          "treat_missing_data" : "notBreaching"
        },
        { "name" : "AAAA",
          "expression" : "m1/(m2-m3)",
          "metrics" : [
            { "id" : "m1", "name" : "BBBB", "statistic" : "Sum", "period" : 21600 },
            { "id" : "m2", "name" : "CCCC", "statistic" : "Sum", "period" : 21600 },
            { "id" : "m3", "name" : "DDDD", "statistic" : "Sum", "period" : 21600 }
          ],
          "threshold" : "0.2",
          "comparison_operator" : "LessThanThreshold",
          "period" : 21600,
          "data_points" : 2,
          "treat_missing_data" : "notBreaching"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Here is the metric alarm declaration:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "metrics-withExpression_alarm" {
  for_each            = local.prefix == "production" ? {} : {for index,m in local.alarm_WithExpression : index => m}
  alarm_name          = "${local.prefix}-${each.value.name}"
  comparison_operator = each.value.comparison_operator
  evaluation_periods  = each.value.period
  threshold           = each.value.threshold
  treat_missing_data  = each.value.treat_missing_data
  datapoints_to_alarm = each.value.data_points

  metric_query {
    id          = "e"
    expression  = each.value.expression
    return_data = "true"
  }

  # loop inside list of metrics ??
  dynamic "metric_query" {
    for_each = {for index,k in local.alarm_WithExpression.metrics : index => k}
    content {
      id = each.value.id

      metric {
        metric_name = each.value.name
        namespace   = "${local.prefix}-metrics"
        period      = each.value.period
        stat        = each.value.statistic
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting this plan error:

```
╷
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│ 
│   on cloudwatch-alarms.tf line 177, in resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "metrics-withExpression_alarm":
│  177:     for_each = {for index,k in local.alarm_WithExpression.metrics : index => k}
│     ├────────────────
│     │ local.alarm_WithExpression is tuple with 2 elements
│ 
│ This value does not have any attributes.
╵
ERROR: 1
```

How to loop through every alarm metrics list?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with this part:

```
local.alarm_WithExpression.metrics
```

To give you some context. `local.alarm_WithExpression` is a list. The list doesn't have a `metrics` property, thus `.metrics` is not giving you what you want.

I believe your goal could be achieved using what they call [splat expressions](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/splat.html), i.e.

```
local.alarm_WithExpression[*].metrics
```

which can be understood in plain English as:

> for every object in `local.alarm_withExpression` take its `metrics` property

Comment: I got this error as it can only see the first for_each statement:  each.value is object with 8 attributes
│ 
│ This object does not have an attribute named "id".

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this like below

```
  dynamic "metric_query" {
    for_each = each.value.metrics
    content {
      id = metrics.value["id"]

      metric {
        metric_name = metrics.value["name"]
        namespace   = "${local.prefix}-metrics"
        period      = metrics.value["period"]
        stat        = metrics.value["statistic"]
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I tried it and got the following error:

│ Error: Reference to undeclared resource
│ 
│   on cloudwatch-alarms.tf line 179, in resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "metrics-withExpression_alarm":
│  179:       id = metrics.value["id"]
│ 
│ A managed resource "metrics" "value" has not been declared in the root module.
╵